# How to set a placeholder for <select> for undefined, null and empty string?

Tags: javascript, angular, select, angular-forms

I try to write a library with a dropdown input. When the Value of the model is either an empty string or null or undefined, the select input should show a placeholder. The problem is, it only works for one of these.

```
<select [formControl]="formControl" value="" title="{{placeholder}}">
    <option disabled hidden [value]="null">{{placeholder}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let key of keys()" value="{{dict[key]}}">{{dict[key]}}</option>
</select>
```

I tried to add more then one option for the placeholder. This worked in Chrome and Firefox, but Safari and IE11 show the placeholder three times.

```
<select [formControl]="formControl" value="" title="{{placeholder}}">
    <option disabled hidden [value]="null">{{placeholder}}</option>
    <option disabled hidden [value]="undefined">{{placeholder}}</option>
    <option disabled hidden [value]="''">{{placeholder}}</option>
    <option *ngFor="let key of keys()" value="{{dict[key]}}">{{dict[key]}}</option>
</select>
```

Is there any way to show a specific value in all other cases except the options, which are defined?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind for me is: why do you have 3 empty values? Maybe your problem is simpler if you supported only `""` empty string.

Comment: Clients don't know about undefined or null.  Or is this a site just for you (for example to generate SQL strings...)?

Comment: @Halcyon: your suggestion does not work if you programmatically set a null value.

Comment: @Emmanuel Delay: clients dont, but programmers, who use my library, do :)

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke I don't see why that's a problem. Simply don't set a `null` value. A `<select>` only supports string values so it doesn't really make sense to set it to `"null"` and expect something special to happen.

Comment: @Halcyon for null values its ok, but what if the value is undefined? If a model is not initialised for example.

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke that's what you have to ask yourself. What does it mean when a model is uninitialized? Does the entry not exist? Does the entry not exist _yet_? Is it even a valid request?

Comment: @Halcyon if a value is not set yet, the placeholder should be set. this is a very common requirement. at least for me :)

Comment: @FranziskusKarsunke that's not entirely true. Again a `<select>` only understands strings and it doesn't have a concept of a 'placeholder'. Consider an `<input type="text" placeholder="foo">`. The placeholder text shows when the value is _empty_. Not when it is `null`, `"null`", `undefined` or `"undefined"` but `""`.